# Как разместить ссылки по центру страницы?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Хочу разместить ссылки по центру страницы, но если ссылки не помещаются в один ряд, то сделать перенос блока с ссылкой. Сейчас у меня так:

```css
.buttons-in-row {
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
}

.but {
  width: 215px;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s linear;
  transition: 0.3s linear;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #19191b;
  float: left;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

.but:hover,
.but:focus {
  background-color: #f3c433;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #19191b inset;
}
```

```html
<div style="buttons-in-row">
  <div>
    <a class="but" href="#">Скачать прайс</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a class="but" href="#">Заказать услугу</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ссылки почему-то всегда слева.

Как выровнять их по центру?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В первой строке html ошибка. Не

```
<div style="buttons-in-row">
```

а

```
<div class="buttons-in-row">
```

И надо ещё `flex-wrap: wrap;`

```css
.buttons-in-row {
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: row;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.but {
  width: 215px;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s linear;
  transition: 0.3s linear;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #19191b;
  float: left;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

.but:hover,
.but:focus {
  background-color: #f3c433;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #19191b inset;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons-in-row">
  <div>
    <a class="but" href="#">Скачать прайс</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a class="but" href="#">Заказать услугу</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Час сидел думал, в чем дело и проморгал style="" (:

Comment: там не только style.Без wrap не работает

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.